# How do I convert a VM snapshot creation time to use in a math equation?

Tags: ansible

[EDIT] I am editing the original question for more clarity

I am trying to build an Ansible script that will delete snapshots over 10 days old. The value that is returned by community.vmware.vmware_guest_snapshot_info is formatted this way `'2022-09-10T15:29:06.888990+00:00'` I want to convert it to only be `2022-09-10` so I can then subtract it from a value produced by `date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d) }}"`I have tried to convert it using to_datetime this way:

```
snap_info['guest_snapshots']['current_snapshot']['creation_time']|to_datetime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%S.%f%z")
```

But I get an error `ValueError: time data '2022-09-10T15:29:06.888990+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%S.%f%z'` Am I using the wrong conversion? Is to_datetime what I want?

Comment: Why are you using “%y-%b-%d instead of “%y-%d-%d”?

Comment: You can delete a VMware Snapshot after it has been combined or else deleted within the VMware menu.  It is not a timed thing.

Comment: @Ramhound because the return value is YYYY-MM-DD and I was reading this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015711/time-data-does-not-match-format and it indicated the format needed to match.

Comment: @John the whole point to this is to have a process run every night deleting snapshots over X days old.

Comment: I understand what you say , but if a snapshot is deleted that should have been combined, that can possibly damage the main VM.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen - **Well %b is absolutely incorrect.** The answer you got that from even said as much. It probably should be %m instead I have no idea what %b would stand for in a DateTime format, if you know, edit your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry I got the %b from this article: https://medium.com/opsops/working-with-dates-and-times-in-ansible-b7dca3e63bba and in rereading it %b is the NAME of the month and I don't want that either. As you pointed out I want %m

Comment: @John in the Ansible script I am using the `remove_all` state which consolidates (combines) all of the snapshots into the master disk.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I changed `to_datetime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%S.%f%z")` to `to_datetime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")`. it took awhile and I want to thank @Ramhound for point out the month number vs. month name in the formatting.